# SIGILL termination from BOOST Log library on QNX 7.1

Tags: signals, qnx-neutrino

I am encountering a SIGILL runtime exception when attempting to use BOOST log in my embedded application on my new QNX 7.1 OS machine. The exception occurs whenever I invoke BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace). The error message reads as follows:

Process xxxxxx terminated SIGILL code=1 fltno=1 ip=000000186b09196(libBoostLogLibrary.so@_ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix4core11open_recordERKNS1_13attribute_setE+0x0000000480) mapaddre=000xx ref=000xx.

According to the QNX 7.1 documentation, this exception is thrown when an illegal instruction is encountered. QNX document suggests enabling privileges for the calling process for SIGILL. By enabling process using procmgr_ability(processPid, 0); issue still persist. The documentation can be found here: https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/s/signalaction.html.